# JSON parsing using Gson returns an error for a boolean value

Tags: android, json, kotlin, gson

I have the following json generated from a WordPress Post:

```
    {  
   "events":[  
      {  
         "id":4651,
         "title":"Test title",
         "description":"testttt",
         "image": {
            url: "https://myhost.tv/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/event2.jpg",
            id: "4652"}
       }
       ]
 }
```

My model for json is as follows:

```
    data class EventsFeed(val events: Array<Events>)

    data class Events (

        val id : Int,
        val title : String,
        val description : String,
        val image : Image
    )


    data class Image (
        val url : String,
        val id : Int,
    )
```

I do the parsing with Json and everything works fine, but when I do a POST in wordpress and I don't put an image, the value of the `Image` key puts me as a`false`, like this:

```
{  
   "events":[  
      {  
         "id":4651,
         "title":"Stand Up Comedy",
         "description":"testttt",
         "image":false
       }
       ]
 }
```

And just because `image` has the value`false`, the parsing returns an error: `Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BOOLEAN at line 1 column 5781 path $ .events [1] .image`

What can I do so that when the post has no image to parse correctly ignoring the value `false` or in any case if it is`false` please keep it a default image (`https://myhost.com/image_defaul.jpg`)

**The json is generated** by the plugin for Wordpress: The Events Calendar: [Demo json here](https://wpshindig.com/wp-json/tribe/events/v1/events)

My function (usen Volley and Gson) for parsing is as follows (the data array is sent to an adapter for display in a recyclerview)

```
fun jsonObjectRequest() {
    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "jsonObjectRequest")

    // Instantiate the RequestQueue.
    val queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(activity)

    val url = "https://myhost.tv/wp-json/tribe/events/v1/events"

    // Request a JSONObject response from the provided URL.
    val jsonObjectRequest = JsonObjectRequest( url, null,
        Response.Listener { response ->
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Response is: $response")

            val gson = Gson()
            val homeEvents  = gson.fromJson(response.toString(), EventsFeed::class.java)

            activity?.runOnUiThread {
                recyclerEvents.adapter = AdaptadorEventos(homeEvents)

            }   
        },
        Response.ErrorListener { error ->
            error.printStackTrace()
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "That didn't work!")
        }
    )

    // Add the request to the RequestQueue.
    queue.add(jsonObjectRequest)
}
```

Comment: At first, you should change your server response so that you set the image field to null when there is no image. Second solution is that you have to manually parse the response by the jsonparser.

Answer (score 2):

The reason why your post method is not getting the Image Class object is because of the json is not a valid json, You may validate it on https://jsonlint.com/. The reason is:  `"url"` and `"id"` keys are not surrounded by "". Take a look at the below solution, it works perfectly:

```
package com.example.myapplication

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
import com.google.gson.Gson

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        getEvemtsObject()

    }

    private val jsonString = " {\n" +
            " \t\"events\": [{\n" +
            " \t\t\"id\": 4651,\n" +
            " \t\t\"title\": \"Test title\",\n" +
            " \t\t\"description\": \"testttt\",\n" +
            " \t\t\"image\": {\n" +
            " \t\t\t\"url\": \"https://myhost.tv/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/event2.jpg\",\n" +
            " \t\t\t\"id\": \"4652\"\n" +
            " \t\t}\n" +
            " \t}]\n" +
            " }"

    private fun getEvemtsObject() {
        val gson = Gson()
        System.out.println("from_gson  ---> " + gson.fromJson<EventsFeed>(jsonString,EventsFeed::class.java))
    }

}
```

Comment: The json is generated by the plugin for Wordpress: The Events Calendar: Demo https://wpshindig.com/wp-json/tribe/events/v1/events. Parsing events work correctly for me, the problem comes when I create an event and I don't attach an image.

Comment: Make the Image key nullable. "val image : Image?" so Incase when you are not attaching the image. the default value to be sent should be "null" instead of "false".

Comment: tried parsing after removing the image key. it works fine for me...       

            private val jsonString1 = "{\n" +
            "\t\"events\": [{\n" +
            "\t\t\"id\": 4651,\n" +
            "\t\t\"title\": \"Test title\",\n" +
            "\t\t\"description\": \"testttt\"\n" +
            "\t}]\n" +
            "}"







private fun getEvemtsObject() {
        val gson = Gson()
        System.out.println("from_gson  ---> " + gson.fromJson<EventsFeed>(jsonString1, EventsFeed::class.java))
    }

Answer (score 1):

You can use custom Gson deserializer like this:

```
class EventsDeserializer : JsonDeserializer<Events> {
    override fun deserialize(json: JsonElement, typeOfT: Type, context: JsonDeserializationContext): Events {
        val jsonObject = json.asJsonObject
        return Events(
            id = jsonObject.get("id").asInt,
            title = jsonObject.get("title").asString,
            description = jsonObject.get("description").asString,
            image = parseImage(context, jsonObject.get("image"))
        )
    }

    private fun parseImage(context: JsonDeserializationContext, json: JsonElement): Image =
        try {
            context.deserialize(json, Image::class.java)
        } catch (_: Throwable) {
            Image("https://myhost.com/image_defaul.jpg", 0)
        }
}
```

and here is the test of your json:

```
fun main() {
    val gson = GsonBuilder()
        .registerTypeAdapter(Events::class.java, EventsDeserializer())
        .create()
    val json = """
{
  "events": [
    {
      "id": 4651,
      "title": "Stand Up Comedy",
      "description": "testttt",
      "image": false
    }
  ]
}
    """.trimIndent()
    val events = gson.fromJson(json, EventsFeed::class.java)
}
```

Comment: I need to have it in an array to pass it to a recyclerview.

Comment: yep, do you have any problems with it?

Answer (score 1):

the image parameter in constructor should be nullable.
rewrite your class like this

```
data class Events (

    val id : Int,
    val title : String,
    val description : String,
    var image : Image? = null)
```

and change your API to send `null` instead of `false`.

Answer (score 0):

This might also be an option (but fixing the API is the better option):

```
val image: Any
```